# Jest Test Fails because of function passed in props to Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am passing a function from the parent in props to the child, my test fails with the following error:

```
  - TypeError: this.props.pageError is not a function
        at ProductForm.handleSubmit (src/js/components/Product/ProductForm
```

I am calling the function:`this.props.pageError(true)` in child to pass some data back to the parent, any ideas why is my test failing?

In parent I have:

```
<ProductForm pageError={this.showText}/>

function definition is:

showText(error) {
    if(error){
      this.setState({pageError: true});
    }
  }
```

and then in child I have:

```
this.props.pageError(true);
```

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Code is too long but I can show the key areas. I'm passing to prop in parent like this:
<ProductForm pageError={this.showText}/>

function definition is:

showText(error) {
    if(error){
      this.setState({pageError: true});
    }
  }

and then in child I have:

this.props.pageError(true);

Comment: ok update your question

Comment: I updated the question, any ideas?